# How to solve the cyclicity in a sphere?

Tags: c, geometry, gis

I find the neighbor cell of A(lat1, 0)(in (lat, lon) and lon is between 0-360 degrees), search return a point B:(lat2,359).

I want to judge which quadrant is B located in(use A as the original point of coordinates)?

In this problem I have two questions:
    1). I can use cross product by the 4-coordinates to judge direction but the (lat2, 359) is in the right direction according to the Rectangular Plane Coordinate System and actually I want the (lat2, -1) instead of (lat2, 359), how to deal with the case?
    2). In a sphere within what km can I regard distance as line in stead of great circle?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust your longitude to a range of -180 to 180.  This can be done by adjusting the variable's value as follows:

```
if (lon > 180.0) lon -= 360.0;
```

Or by using `(lon > 180.0 ? lon - 360.0 : lon)` instead of just `lon`, which leaves the original value of `lon` intact.

You should probably do the same for the latitude.